# What is the preferred way to initialize a class in C++

Tags: c++

Which of the two initialization styles below is preferred when programming in C++, class A which initializes values in the constructor or B where data members have default initialization?

```
//A.h

class A{

A();

int value;
string name;
bool aSwitch;

}

//A.cpp
...

A::A():
  value(0),
  name("joe"),
  aSwitch(false)
{ }
```

or

```
//B.h

class B{

B();

int value = 0;
string name = "joe";
bool aSwitch = false;

}

//B.cpp
...

B::B()
{ }
```

Are there any advantages or disadvantages to any of these two styles?

Comment: Opinion based & too broad me thinks; because the answer depends on if the class has meaning/value if it's members don't have values.

Comment: The advantage of `B` is that you don't need `B::B()`, but you kinda lost out on that.

Comment: This is very use-case dependent. Method B can't be used if you need to pass an argument to the constructor for example.

Comment: `switch` is a keyword by the way, you can't use it as a variable name.

Comment: There are advantages and disadvantages to either approach. That's why they exist. In some cases one is more convenient, in others it's the other one. Rather than looking for some magical "this is better always use this" button, you should spend the time understanding how either approach works and what it means, and then you'll be in a better position to make an intelligent choice as to which one will work better for your, specific, use case.

Comment: When in doubt go for readability.

Comment: @nwp: if you remove user defined constructor, then `B` might be aggregate initialized...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple constructors, and a class member that is always going to be initialized with the same value in each of the constructors, then you should initialize it when you declare it. In all other cases, it is probably a better idea to initialize in the constructor initializer list.

Example:

```
class A
{
    int a = 0;
    int b;
    int c;
public:
    A(int x) : b{ x }, c{ x } { }
    A()      : b{ 1 }, c{ 0 } { }
};
```

In the example above, if you wanted `a` to always be 0 for either constructor, then to remove duplication, you would initialize `a` when you declare it.

Comment: in your example would the A() constructor cause 'int b;' to be assigned a random value and similarly the A(int x) constructor cause 'int c;' to be also assigned a random value on construction?

Comment: @JozefMilenkiewicz I have edited to make sure all variables are initialized.